# How this dilemma (about freedom) go? And where is it from?

Tags: free-will, freedom

I'm not sure if this is the right SE to ask, but it seemed like the best fit.

I once saw this "*dilemma*" in the internet, but I don't remember where or exactly how it goes, I hope someone herealready saw it or saw something similar. It was something like this:

> You are followed by a *guard/policeman/armed man*(??) your entire
>   life. He tells you that if you ever break a law (*I also can't remember
>   if it's about laws*) he would shoot you dead. *[On this hypothetical
>   situation you can't evade the guard]*
>
> You live your entire life and he never does anything else, until you die from natural causes. Were you free?

My question is what is the right dilemma/story/situation? And does someone knows where is it from? Or maybe who the author is?

PS.: Yes, I already looked in google.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Philosophy SE! - Have a look at :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panopticism

Comment: This sounds like a folk version of [Frankfurt's free will thought experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt_cases). In the original set-up the person gets implanted with a mind control device ("policeman") that gets activated, and stops them, only if they intend to do something undesirable for the implanter ("break the law"). Frankfurt's point was that one can be morally responsible (or deserve moral credit, in this case) for their actions even if they do not really have an ability to act otherwise. But upon closer analysis it turned out that Frankfurt's point does not quite follow.

Comment: Thank you both! Still want to find the proper 'story', even if it's a folk version, but really appreciate the links, awesome reading.